# How to achieve this layout with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the cards from bootstrap but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve a layout where it looks like this:

```
[card 1 ] [card 2]
          [card 3]
```

where card 1 and card 2 are equal width across the page and card 3 is below but under card 2 to the right

I try to use `pull right` or `float right` but no luck.

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: use bootstrap grid system : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @karen added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, put the card 2 and card 3 in the same column:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. I'll vote your answer when im able to. Can't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2> Card</h2>
  <div class = "row">
  <div class="card col-md-6">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card 1</div>
  </div>

   <div class="card col-md-6">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card 2</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "row">
  <div class=" col-md-6">
  </div>

   <div class="card col-md-6">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card 3</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that OP already got his answer and that he is using Bootstrap, but I just want to add that for scenarios where there is a need for grid formating of element, [CSS grid](https://learncssgrid.com/) might be a better choice than Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks I'll fersure take a look at that!